# Button Group and OptionStepper

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs6

I am currently doing an Option Menu for a game.

I am stuck at the AS3 code error.

```
import gfx.controls.ButtonGroup;
import scaleform.clik.controls.ButtonGroup;

aaBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, EnableAARadioButtons);
difficultyOption.dataProvider = ["Easy", "Medium", "Hard"];

var aaGroup:ButtonGroup = new ButtonGroup();
edgeaaBtn.group = hwaaBtn.group = aaGroup;

stop();

function EnableAARadioButtons()
{
    edgeaaBtn.disabled = hwaaBtn.disabled = !aaBtn.selected;
}
```

and it gives me the following error,

```
Scene 1, Layer 'actions', Frame 10, Line 1, Column 20   1172: Definition gfx.controls:ButtonGroup could not be found.
Scene 1, Layer 'actions', Frame 10, Line 1, Column 20   1172: Definition gfx.controls:ButtonGroup could not be found.
Scene 1, Layer 'actions', Frame 10, Line 5, Column 33   1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type Array to an unrelated type scaleform.clik.interfaces:IDataProvider.
Scene 1, Layer 'actions', Frame 10, Line 7, Column 31   1136: Incorrect number of arguments.  Expected 2.
```

I can't seem to fix this problem.

When I remove  `import gfx.controls.ButtonGroup;`, it left with only the dataProvider error. Please Help.

Comment: Is it `ScaleForm` gfx?

Comment: yes it is a scalefrom gfx

Comment: ok i figure out the first problem it was
import scaleform.clik.data.DataProvider;